# python - PyQt detect when worker is finished and do something in main thread

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyqt

i have an issue, I am newbie to PyQt and I can't figure out how to detect when my worker(thread got finished) using main thread(the UI thread)..
so basically what I want to says :
I have a class which create UI and a bunch of widget and when i click a button my **Qthread**  run with success the **problem** is i can't detect when my thread is done...because I want to start a new UI when the thread is done .. and when i do this from inside the thread i got an error :

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

So please if anyone knows  how to detect finish SIGNAL of my thread using the Main Thread which is the  UI thread

anyway here is my code .. that i tried so far

```
from  PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Log In to your facebook account")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("../data/facebook.ico"))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #3b5998;")

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        """Create facebook login ui"""
        LineEditStyle = "background-color: white;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; font-size: 14px; font-family: consolas;" \
                        "border: 2px solid #3BBCE3; border-radius: 4px;"

        logo = QtGui.QLabel("Facebook")
        logo.setStyleSheet("font-size: 50px; font-weight:bold;color:white;")
        logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        trustus = QtGui.QLabel("This Feature requires you to sign in to your facebook account.\n"
                               "Please enter your facebook email and password, trust us, we won't steal your \n"
                               "login info, you're in control + you can always go back if you want.")

        email = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        email.setPlaceholderText("Your facebook email address")
        email.setStyleSheet(LineEditStyle)

        password = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        password.setPlaceholderText("Your facebook password")
        password.setStyleSheet(LineEditStyle)

        login = QtGui.QPushButton("Log In")
        login.clicked.connect(lambda: self.login(email.text(), password.text()))
        login.setStyleSheet("background: #2A49A5;border: 1px solid #082783;color: white;padding: 10px;"
                            "text-decoration: none;font: 12px Verdana, sans-serif;")

        keepLogin = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        keepLogin.setEnabled(True)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(logo)
        layout.addWidget(trustus)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(email)
        layout.addWidget(password)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(login)

    def look(self):
        print("oh you made it, this method got run from insid the main thread insteed the ")

    def login(self, email, password):
        if not email.strip() or not email.find("@") or not password.strip():
            print("please insert a valid entry")
        else:
            self.thread = LoginWorker(email, password)
            self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.look)
            self.thread.start()


class LoginWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, facebook_email, facebook_password, parent=None):
        super(LoginWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.email = facebook_email
        self.password = facebook_password
        self.driver = None

        self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")

    def run(self):

        if self.driver is None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        else:
            self.driver.quit()
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.emit(self.signal, "hi from thread")

        self.driver.get("https://wwww.facebook.com/")
        self.test_login()

    def test_login(self):
        emailFieldID = "email"
        passFieldID = "pass"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value='Log In']"

        emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID))
        passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
        loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

        emailFieldElement.clear()
        emailFieldElement.send_keys(self.email)

        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(self.password)

        loginButtonElement.click()

        self.checkLogin()

    def checkLogin(self):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")
            print("You're not logged in..")
        except:
            """after the execution of this line right here it will be great if i could run the method done() using the Main Thread instead of  the worker.. i hope you got what I am trying to see"""
            print("You're Logged in")
            self.driver.quit()


def done():
    print("this method (done) needs to be run from the Main Thread :(, i will be happy if you could make it runs from the Main thread.. :) because later on this print will be replaced by the code that could run my new Window..:)")
```

**Please note that i use PyQt4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define signals dynamically on instances, they have to be declared as class attributes.  Also, `SIGNAL` is only used with the old-style syntax, which nobody uses anymore, for the new-style signal/slot syntax use `pyqtSignal` and `pyqtSlot`.  Also, the arguments to the `pyqtSignal` should be the class types for the objects that will be `emit`'d through the signal.  So you can't do this

```
self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")
```

You would do this instead

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        self.signal.emit('The string sent through the signal')
```

On the other side, you should declare your slots

```
class Window(...):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def look(self, msg):
        print msg

    def ...
        thread = MyThread()
        thread.signal.connect(self.look)
```

If you don't care about passing data back from the thread and *only* care about when it's finished

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def look(self):
        print 'Thread finished'

    def ...
        thread = MyThread()
        thread.finished.connect(self.look)
```

Comment: It Deosn't work it says
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aouak\PycharmProjects\FriendsInfoScrapper\Facebook\FacebookLogin.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    login.clicked.connect(lambda: self.login(email.text(), password.text()))
  File "C:\Users\aouak\PycharmProjects\FriendsInfoScrapper\Facebook\FacebookLogin.py", line 71, in login
    self.thread.signal.connect(self.look)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'connect'

Comment: Not sure without seeing your code, but it says `thread.signal` is a bytes object, not a signal

Comment: i upload my code to Pastebin for you this is the [link](http://pastebin.com/6bsr6Dd4)

Comment: @Alfa please read the provided answer again, specifically at how to emit a signal. Your code to emit the signal is nothing like the code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks i did and it turn out that the code worked just fine :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

O Thanks Brendan Abel for you answer it did worked when i run your code in simple UI ..

```
from  PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time, sys

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        self.signal.emit(':) Oh I did it the string is final sent over the SIGNAL')

        x = 1
        while x < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            x += 1


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def look(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        print(self.thread.isFinished())

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Log In to your facebook account")

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start Thread", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.handelClick)

    def handelClick(self):
        self.thread = Worker()
        self.thread.signal.connect(self.look)
        self.thread.start()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui  = Window()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'll try to do the same in My Code above.. thanks Again